# How to install sql functions in startup of django app

Tags: django

I have an app that uses sql functions for some of its queries.

For now, I've written an installation function that installs the sql functions through a cursor:

```
def install_all():
    install(FUNC1)
    install(FUNC2)
    install(FUNC3)

def install(script):

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(script)
```

I've added a call to `install_all()` inside one of the project's `__init__.py` so that every time the project is run, it reinstalls the functions (in case they've changed.)

I really do *not* want to do this with manual migrations.

The problem I had recently is that this creates an open connection to the db and prevents things like `manage reset_db` from working because of an open connection.  Even `manage dbshell` opens up with an existing connection to the db from the cursor.  Presumably the cursor executes, the socket isn't closed, and the `exec`'ed `psql` inherits the still open socket.

For now I've changed it to:

```
from django.db import connection    

def install_all():
    install(FUNC1)
    install(FUNC2)
    install(FUNC3)          
    connection.close()
```

...and this works but seems heavy handed.

Is there an explicitly supported way this startup code can be incorporated into a Django App?

version: Django 1.11

Comment: I suggest translating those SQL Functions to Python code. Much more convenient and maintainable solution.

Comment: @agus I’d rather they were too, but I need them to convert certain columns a certain way for sorting in the db.